# What's the best RPG coding practice according to OOP design?

Tags: java, oop

I'm working on a RPG game and there's a `Player` and an `Equipment` class. Should I implement `mountEquipment()` method in `Player` class, which it will be something like

```
public class Player {
    private ArrayList<Equipment> equipments;

    public void mountEquipment(Equipment e){
        // how can i know what attributes
        // Equipment will change in Player?
        equipments.add(e);
    }
}
```

or should I implement in `Equipment` class, which will be

```
public class Equipment {

    public void mountEquipment(Player p){
        // here i can access all Player attributes
        p.addStrength(50);
        p.addHP(100);
        p.addEquipment(this);
    }
}
```

It's easier to acess `Player` attributes defining `mountEquipment` in `Equipment` class, but I think it makes more sense having `mountEquipment` in `Player` class, even thought it will be harder to changing `Player` attributes. For example, a `Sword` can change strength and `MagicWand` can change strenght and luck, for example.

Where should I implement this class in this case?

Comment: Seems more likely that you will want to get each piece of equipment for each player, not a player for a given piece of equipment.

Comment: @Nexevis Because equipments can change different attributes. For example, if I equip a sword, it will only change strength, but if I equip a magic wand, it will change strength and luck. How can I distinguish what attributes to change in `Player` class? One could do `if (e.getClass().getName().equals("Sword")) this.strength += 40; else if (e.getClass().getName().equals("MagicWand")){ this.luck += 30; this.strenght += 50; }`, but I think that's a lot of work.

Comment: @desmong_jones You could change them all every time, except a `Sword` changes luck by `0`, while Magic Wand would not.  You could have a method that reads all the stats on an `Equipment` and use it accordingly.  The `Equipment` should know its own stats in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simple case, a player's stats are basically just an aggregation of their base stats + their equipment stats.

Seems like an opportunity to share an interface:

```
public interface StatProvider {
    int health();

    int intellect();
}

public class Ring implements StatProvider {
    @Override
    public int health() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int intellect() {
        return 5;
    }
}

public class Mage implements StatProvider {

    private final int baseHealth = 100;
    private final int baseIntellect = 20;

    private List<StatProvider> equipment;

    @Override
    public int health() {
        return baseHealth + equipment.stream().mapToInt(StatProvider::health).sum();
    }

    @Override
    public int intellect() {
        return baseIntellect + equipment.stream().mapToInt(StatProvider::intellect).sum();
    }
}
```

Works well with the decorator pattern too maybe

```
public class HealthDoublingEnchantment implements StatProvider {
    private final StatProvider delegate;

    public HealthDoublingEnchantment(StatProvider delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public int health() {
        return delegate.health() * 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int intellect() {
        return delegate.intellect();
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
new HealthDoublingEnchantment(new Ring());
```